# Cakephp Error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found Error, how can it be fixed?

Tags: php, cakephp

I installed Cakephp as part of my tutorial, and I wanted to start  a basic page with only hello world.

I written the class in the Hellopagecontroller.php < a file i created:

```
<?php

class HelloController extends Controller
{

  public function index()
  {
    echo "Hello, CakePHP World";
  }
}

 ?>
```

An image to illustrate:
[An image of the files I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhsXm.png)

This is the output I have when opening the index page it doesn't show hello, cakephp world rather

> Error: Class 'Controller' not found  File
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Test2/src/Controller/HelloController.php
>   Line: 5

[The error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBmQh.png)

### note: cakePHP version: 3.4.6 - PHP Version:5.6.28

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller) you have to extend the `AppController` instead of the `Controller` class.

Comment: @Tobias or create another controller called Controller that extends AppController. :)

Comment: What tutorial are you following? Either it is wrong, or you're not following it correctly, as you're missing all the stuff regarding namespaces.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: @ndm There is no use or namespace before the class name in the tutorial. what I'm missing?

Comment: @RayannNayran I edited the question with the versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing out to declare the `namespace`, and you should extends your class from `AppController`.

If you are new on CakePHP framwork, I highly recommend you check the [Bookmarker Tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html) out.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

class HelloController extends AppController
{
  public function index()
  {
    echo "Hello, CakePHP World";
  }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: I get this error:
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test2/src/Controller/HelloController.php on line 3

Comment: As the error says, the namespace declaration MUST BE the FIRST statement in the script, meaning you MUST NOT have other statement before, only the php open tag.

Comment: I don't have other statement before i only have php open tag

Comment: Please, update your question with the actual code of your controller.

Comment: Thank you all I solved the issue i'll paste the solution here later

Comment: The solution is as the above however I had space before the <?php removing the space solved the issue with the use of namespace as well thanks

Comment: Yeah, great. :D

Answer (score 0):

Remove all spaces before start of php tag will remove this problem.

Comment: Can you explain that further? What's the reason for that?